# How can I get an intuitive explanation of the visualization of geodesics in a cone?

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

I calculated that the geodesics in a cone satisfy the following formula:

$$r=\frac{1}{Acos(\omega \phi + \alpha)}$$

The cone is parametrised by taking spherical coordinates and fixing $\theta=\theta_0$ such that $\omega=sin(\theta_0)$, and both $A$ and $\alpha$ are parameters of the geodesics equation that will have to be determined by boundary conditions.

Now, I've seen on WolframAlpha that the geodesics in the cone have the following shape:

[image]

I see how $r$ goes to infinity when the cosine is 0, but I can't see why does it has this sort of "8" shape, and how is it that we can get a negative $r$ value from the formula?

It also can be seen in the picture that, for a certain value of $phi$, two $r$ values can be given, and I don't understand that either.

I've also seen that these geodesics are equivalent to a straight line when we slice the cone and "unroll" it into a plane, but I don't see how can I prove that from my geodesics formula.

Comment: In my opinion, the intuitive way to look at these geodesics is precisely what you stated in your last paragraph: you unroll the cone (because it is a flat surface) and draw straight-lines.

Comment: I get that, what I don't see is how that formula plots into that geodesic of the cone (for example, what's with the negative values of r that formula predicts and where did that 8 shape pop out from)

Comment: By the way, $r$ does not admit negative values. As for _two values of $r$ for some value of $\phi$_, this would be easy to explain once you write down what $r,A,\omega,\alpha,\phi$ are.

Comment: Do you know Clairaut's Theorem characterizing geodesics on a surface of revolution?

Comment: Not al all, but I'll check it out!